# I would like to replace a piece of text with the same text and a command

Tags: macros, formatting, texmaker

Units are supposed to be normal but inside an `align` block all the text is *kursiv*.
My usual practice is to just put it inside a `\text` command like

```
\frac{\text{m}}{\text{m}}.
```

I would like to know if there is a way to mark a piece of text (the `m` for example) then press a button combination and it gets replaced by a `\text{m}` and if it is possible how i would do that.
I'm not sure if it is and help/need to be known but I'm using MikTeX and Texmaker.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Which editor are you using?

Comment: @AndrewSwann that would be texmaker

Comment: Maybe you're interested in the `siunitx` package.

Comment: @egreg im looking into it right now (not working yet though) but im still curious if this is possible

Comment: Better than a keyboard shortcut that makes `m` turn into `\text{m}` is a `\newcommand` that controls the whole block:  `\newcommand{\myfrac}[2]{\frac{\text{#1}}{\text{#2}}}`. ... *Then* maybe set up a keyboard shortcut to give you `\myfrac{@}{@}`. However, for this specific issue, you should (also) use the  `siunitx` package: it is designed specifically for getting your units properly typeset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to User --> User Tags --> Edit User Tags. For one of the empty entries, give it a useful name in the *Menu item* field, and type

```
\text{@}
```

in the *LaTeX content* field:

[image]

If you added this in the first one (as in the screenshot), you can select text and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to put the selected text in a `\text{}`. I don't think you can edit the shortcut though.